# Why rust told me that a reference still borrowed at the end of main function?

Tags: rust, traits, lifetime

As you can see in the following code, I have two traits, one is called Hittable, and the other is called Material (I have been studying the book "ray-tracing-in-one-weekend", but use Rust).

The Hittable trait implements hit function for some objects (just like Sphere in this code), and every kind of objects includes its material (just like Glass, Wood...).

In my real project, the Sphere struct and another struct (called HitRecord in this book, used as mut reference to pass result in hit function), they both include `&dyn Material`, so that I need add lifetime parameter for both of them. However, to accomplish that, I should add lifetime parameter in the trait declaration, so I can assign the same lifetime parameter for Sphere and hit.

But the compiler indicates that the reference still under borrowed when the main function ends, I have no idea for that...

```rust
trait Hittable<'a> {
    fn hit(&self);
}

trait Material {
    fn result(&self);
}

struct Glass;

impl Material for Glass {
    fn result(&self) {
        println!("Glass is broken!");
    }
}

struct Sphere<'a> {
    name: String,
    mat_ptr: &'a dyn Material,
}

impl<'a> Hittable<'a> for Sphere<'a> {
    fn hit(&self) {
        println!("Name is {}", self.name);
        self.mat_ptr.result();
    }
}

struct HT<'a> {
    pub objects: Vec<Box<dyn Hittable<'a>>>,
}

fn main() {
    let mut list = HT { objects: vec![] };
    let surface_material = Glass;
    let s = Sphere {
        name: String::from("球"),
        mat_ptr: &surface_material,
    };
    list.objects.push(Box::new(s));
}
```

the message shows

```
Compiling rust_test v0.1.0 (/home/hnyls2002/rust_test)
error[E0597]: `surface_material` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:38:18
   |
38 |         mat_ptr: &surface_material,
   |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |                  |
   |                  borrowed value does not live long enough
   |                  cast requires that `surface_material` is borrowed for `'static`
...
41 | }
   | - `surface_material` dropped here while still borrowed

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0597`.
```

Comment: When I use the Vec instead of my HT struct, it won't be wrong, maybe because the HT's lifetime?

Comment: If you're looking to share data like that, consider `Rc`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `dyn Hittable<'a>` is actually `dyn Hittable<'a> + 'static`, and thus `s` is required to live for `'static`. The fix is to change `HT` to:

```rust
struct HT<'a> {
    pub objects: Vec<Box<dyn Hittable<'a> + 'a>>,
}
```

Then you'll get a long but pretty self-explanatory error:

```
error[E0597]: `surface_material` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:38:18
   |
38 |         mat_ptr: &surface_material,
   |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
...
41 | }
   | -
   | |
   | `surface_material` dropped here while still borrowed
   | borrow might be used here, when `list` is dropped and runs the destructor for type `HT<'_>`
   |
   = note: values in a scope are dropped in the opposite order they are defined
```

Because `surface_material` is defined after `list`, it'll be dropped before and when the potential destructor for `dyn Hittable` will run it may access the freed `surface_material`. The fix is just to swap the declaration order of `list` and `surface_material`:

```rust
fn main() {
    // always define before the container you are pushing into
    let surface_material = Glass;
    let mut list = HT { objects: vec![] };
    // ...
}
```